# Can I use D'Fusion as the Augmented Reality Authoring Tool for Metaio?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Like the title says. Can I use D'Fusion as the authoring tool for metaio (as for metaio's own authoring tool, you have to buy a licence)?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

Metaio's sdk is  free though. You only have to buy a license if your need to get rid of the watermark. Otherwise, pretty much all of the functions an features are there for unlimited use.